# Cache rebuild causes an error with missing plugin

Tags: drush, caching, plugins

On rebuilding the cache, a Drupal 8 website goes down and displays the message "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later." I used `drush cr` to rebuild the cache, which shows the following error message.

> The "field_item:boolean" plugin does not exist.

I also tried to rebuild the cache right after installing a new Drupal 8 site without any additional module, and it shows the same error.

How can I get the site back to working?

Comment: If you can't access the dblog of drupal then see your apache logs and post here what you find

Comment: When the plugin discovery fails in downloaded code, then this is most times a download error, so the first thing you should try is to remove the code base and download it again.

Comment: @4k4 It is not a download error. This happens on every drupal 8 project.

Comment: @GiorgosK Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "field_item:boolean" plugin does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->doGetDefinition() (line 52 of /var/www/html/drupal_8/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php).  is the error I get

Comment: @Nabil what php version do you have `php -v` ? try running `drush entity-update` see if it helps.  If you have contrib modules disable them.  What exact version of drupal do you have ?

Comment: @GiorgosK php version is 7.1.9 , drupal 8.4.4

Comment: @GiorgosK drush entity-update is not helping. But after clearing cache_discovery table via phpmyadmin site is up and running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This morning I had similar problem and `drush cr` was actually not clearing the discovery cache but after

```
drush sql-query 'TRUNCATE TABLE cache_discovery;'
```

I was able to get rid of this error